# Why do these 9 U.S. cities not correspond to their actual locations on a D3 map when I plot them using long/lat with an Albers USA projection?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to set up what seemed to be a basic D3 map of the U.S., with 9 of the most populated cities marked in circles, but have come up against what must be a very obvious, but confounding problem.

I'm using an **Albers USA projection**, a **U.S. states GeoJSON file**, and a **.csv** that includes:

1. The city name
2. The 2014 estimated population
3. The latitude
4. The longitude

I've calculated the long/lat values using Google Fusion tables' geocoding feature, and they match up with those available on [Scott Murray's D3 book github page](https://github.com/alignedleft/d3-book/blob/master/chapter_12/us-cities.csv).

When I try to plot a circle where each city should be, almost every single one is out of place. Of the 9 cities I'm trying to plot — NYC, Philadelphia, Chicago, Houston, Dallas, San Antonio, Phoenix, San Diego, LA — only NYC and Philadelphia show up relatively intact. Chicago's shifted over towards Minneapolis. San Diego and LA are a mess. Cities in Texas and Arizona have disappeared from their states altogether.

Here's the d3.csv code:

```
        d3.csv("city_pop.csv", function(data){
                console.log(data);
            var rScale = d3.scale.linear()
                            .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){
                                return parseFloat(d.estimate_2014);
                            })])
                            .range([1,15]);

            dataset = data;

            svg.selectAll("circle")
            .data(dataset)
            .enter()
            .append("circle")
            .attr({
                "cx": function(d) { return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[0];},
                "cy": function(d) { return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[1];},
                "r": function (d) { return rScale(parseFloat(d.estimate_2014));}
            })
            .style({
                "fill": "red",
                "opacity": 0.8
            });
        });
```

Here's the gist: http://bl.ocks.org/iblind/2e90a6f516fee793380e

I've been playing with this all day. Does anyone have any ideas? I've been banging my head against the wall for what feels like forever, and am wholly lost.

> tl;dr: why do the cities in this D3 map
>   http://bl.ocks.org/iblind/2e90a6f516fee793380e not show up where they
>   should be showing up?

Comment: Please add your code _to the question_, not link to an external site.

Comment: @xxbbcc thanks, I added the d3.csv( ) code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base data is wrong  (city_pop.csv). Run your latitudes and longitudes through Google Map and you'll see the same pattern forms.
For example Philadelphia,Pennsylvania (37.15477,-94.486114) is not where Pennsylvania is - https://goo.gl/maps/1G754

Comment: Bingo. Thanks. If this isn't a lesson in checking the integrity of a dataset, I don't know what is.

Comment: NP, happens to all of us. Also created a map with all of the coordinates - https://www.google.com/maps/d/edit?mid=z59ZGT1mTGlY.kZkDYL7NrKGw&usp=sharing